# Проверка наличия в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
        Array 
        ( [0] => Array ( 
    [attribute_group_id] => 8 [name] => Газоблок 
    [attribute] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [attribute_id] => 31 
[name] => Применение 
[text] => Перегородочный блок ) [1] => Array ( 
    [attribute_id] => 32 
[name] => Марка плотности [text] => D600 ) 
[2] => Array (
    [attribute_id] => 33 [name] => Класс прочности [text] => Б2,5 ) [3] => Array ( [attribute_id] => 34 [name] => Длина, мм [text] => 625 ) [4] => Array ( [attribute_id] => 35 [name] => Ширина, мм [text] => 100 ) [5] => Array ( [attribute_id] => 36 [name] => Высота, мм [text] => 250 ) [6] => Array ( [attribute_id] => 37 [name] => Количество блоков в поддоне, шт [text] => 48 ) [7] => Array ( 
    [attribute_id] => 38 [name] => Вес поддона, кг [text] => 560 ) [8] => Array ( [attribute_id] => 39 [name] => Объём поддона, м3 [text] => 0,75 ) [9] => Array ( 
    [attribute_id] => 40 [name] => Размер поддона с продукцией, м [text] => 1.0/0.625/1.305 ) [10] => Array ( 
    [attribute_id] => 153 [name] => Минимальный заказ (куб. м) [text] => 1 ) ) ) )
```

Как проверить наличие в массиве-массивах "Минимальный заказ (куб. м)" ?

in_array и array_search пока не получается победить у меня.

Comment: используйте array_walk_recursive() .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Набросал "на коленке", попробуйте работает или нет:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($item, $key) {
    if ('Минимальный заказ (куб. м)' == $item) {
        echo  $item;
    }
});
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо